# intent filter category android.intent.category.default Default Activity not found

Tags: android, android-intent, android-launcher

```
         <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".AppListActivity"/>
</application>
```

here android.category.default is used to make this application as default launcher like google launcher but when running this application its throwing error default activity not found...i have tried restarting and invalidating cache several times.  can anyone help me...?

Comment: What are you trying to archive? Are you creating home launcher?

Comment: yes i am trying to make a home launcher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this,

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"
    android:stateNotNeeded="true">
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to Edit Configurations. Within the General tab, in the launch options drop down, select nothing. Now run the app.

You can use `Control + Shift + A` on Windows or `Command + Shift + A` on Mac, and type edit configurations to open it.

Answer (score -1):

Just specify activity to lunch in android studio. To do that click on `run configuration` -> `Edit configurations`.

In `Launch Options` pick `Specified Activity` and then select your activity.

[image]